# How can I synchronize the resizing of two textareas automatically with JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 2 textareas. How to make stretching or shrinking them vertically simultaneous? That is, stretching  or shrinking one textarea automatically stretches or shrinks another.

And by the way, I don't need horizontal scrolling. I want the text to stretch vertically.

How can I do that?

```js
let oldHeight1 = 0;
let oldHeight2 = 0;

const ro = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  let entry = entries[0];

  let height1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("textarea1")).getPropertyValue('height');
  
  let height2 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("textarea2")).getPropertyValue('height');
  

  if (oldHeight1 != height1) {
    document.getElementById("textarea2").style.height = height1;
    height2 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("textarea2")).getPropertyValue('height');
  
  oldHeight1 = height1;
  oldHeight2 = height2;
  }
  if (oldHeight2 != height2) {
    document.getElementById("textarea1").style.height = height2;
    height1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("textarea1")).getPropertyValue('height');
    
    oldHeight1 = height1;
    oldHeight2 = height2; 
  }

  console.log(" h1=" + height1 + "  h2=" + height2);


});

ro.observe(document.querySelector("#textarea1"));
ro.observe(document.querySelector("#textarea2"));
```

```css
.container_label_textarea {
  background: rgb(119, 128, 0);
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.label {
  width: 50%;
  background: rgb(182, 10, 238);
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.textarea {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background: rgb(182, 186, 238);
  /*width: calc(50vw - 16px);*/
  text-align: start;
  resize: vertical;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 390px;
  column-width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_label_textarea">
            <div class="label">
                <label class="label" id="Text1" for="textarea1">Text 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                <label class="label" id="Text2" for="textarea2">Text 2</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container_label_textarea">
            <textarea id="textarea1" class="textarea" wrap="on" 
                placeholder="Describe yourself here...">
      </textarea>

            <textarea  id="textarea2" class="textarea" wrap="on" 
                placeholder="Describe yourself here...">
      </textarea>
            <br />
        </div>
```

There are 2 textareas. How to make stretching or shrinking them vertically simultaneous? That is, stretching  or shrinking one textarea automatically stretches or shrinks another.

Comment: It is better to watch the example by expanding the fragment, due to the ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications error. This error is explained on the website: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver". And so the algorithm should be clear from the code

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Resize Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to listen to resize events on each textarea, and in the callback, for each textarea that isn't one of the ones that has changed (isn't in the first argument of the callback), change it to the size of the one that is.